# SelectOneMenu appears only the object and not the content that should

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu that loads a list of BD, debugging can ve that all steps are correct except the time it shows the value in selectOneMenu. On page appears the object name "JanelaPortabilidade @ 7437" and not like the String.

My codes:

```
public List<SelectItem> listarHoraJanela(DateSelectEvent event) {  

        dataF = event.getDate();  
        Calendar dataAux = new GregorianCalendar();               
        dataAux.setTime(dataF);   


        //Corrigir  
        if (listaHoraJanela == null) {  

            listaHoraJanela = new ArrayList<JanelaEAPortabilidade>();  
            listaHoraJanela = consultaJPortabilidade.listarHoraJanela(dataAux);  
            listSelectHoraJ.add(new SelectItem("", ""));              

            for (JanelaEAPortabilidade horaJ : listaHoraJanela) {  
                String dataFormat = String.format("%02d",horaJ.horIniJanela.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));  
                System.out.println(dataFormat);//So here is ok, print in console correct string 
                listSelectHoraJ.add(new SelectItem(horaJ.getIdtJanela(),dataFormat));  


            }  
        }
```

xhtml:

```
<h:outputText value="Hora da Janela:" for="horaJanela" />  
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.codHoraJanela}" id="horaJanela"         
    rendered="#{bean.type == 'Fixo'}" >  
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.listaHoraJanela}" />
```

What can it be? I must be missing something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to use the itemLabel and itemValue attributes for f:selectItems. Here is an example from the PrimeFaces website (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf from the pojo section of the code):

```
<f:selectItems value="#{autoCompleteBean.players}" var="player" itemLabel="#{player.name}" itemValue="#{player}"/>
```

The itemLabel is what will be displayed in the drop down list and itemValue is what will be returned (in #{bean.codHoraJanela} in your example).

Comment: I was able to show with <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listSelectHoraJ}" />. Now how do I get the selected dataFormat? The horaJ.getIdtJanela() selected I can get with codHoraJanela, but do not know how to get the dataFormat selected.

Comment: I suppose you persist the list listSelectHoraJ until the user makes a selection then iterate over it until you find the code they selected. You could then get the label. Since your list appears to go out of scope you are going to to need to move your declaration to somewhere that persists through the lifecycle. It is possible that the whole SelectItem comes back somewhere in the event or context but I don't know. Or, since dataFormat is calculated from horaJ.horIniJanela anyway, you could just re-calculate based on which ID the user selected.

Comment: I solved this way:
`code
for (JanelaEAPortabilidade horaJ: listaHoraJanela) {
 if (horaJ.getIdtJanela (). equals (codHoraJanela)) {
   HoraFormat String = String.format ("% 02d"
   horaJ.horIniJanela.get (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
   DateFormatAux Integer = Integer.parseInt (horaFormat);
   calendarAux.add (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, dateFormatAux);
   parametro.setDateF (calendarAux);
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the code even works. If I didn't miss something the code should throw a `NullPointerException`. In the JSF you posted a `DateSelectEvent` isn't created, instead the method is called without any arguments. The `DateSelectEvent` in the Java method should therefor be `NULL`.

The output you see is the result of an object's `toString()` method. Probably the object represented there is coming from the `codHoraJanela` method in the managed bean. Fix the `listarHoraJanela` method to return a list of objects.

Comment: `listarHoraJanela` != `listaHoraJanela`. The method shown by the OP is likely a listener method which is invoked by `<p:calendar>`.